# How do I set the text value of a label to a global variable in my .kv file?

Tags: python, kivy

A part of my program involves user inputting there own text.
I want a label to change to the value of the input, which will be stored in a global variable.

Basically what's happening

```py
chosen = StringProperty()
```

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:layout
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: #What do I put here?
            font_size: 25
            padding: 10, 0
            text_size: root.width, None
            size: self.texture_size
            size_hint_y:3
```

I want the text to change as as the variable changes, and I want to control what the variable value from 2 different classes.

Comment: Post a minimal *runnable* example, i.e. enough code that it actually runs but no more than enough to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: `Properties` only work inside classes that extend `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: I'm sorry for not pasting the code. It is available here: https://pastebin.com/00dx1xGp

Answer (score 0):

you can use the app keyword that will let you access the variable in your python script

```
text: app.chosen
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accepting the input in the `.py` file then you can use the `ObjectProperty`

.kv file

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id:layout
        lab:lab
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            id: lab
            text: 'anything'
            font_size: 25
            padding: 10, 0
            text_size: root.width, None
            size: self.texture_size
            size_hint_y:3
```

in .py file

```
lab = ObjectProperty()
txt = input('Dear User, please enter a value : ')
self.lab.text=txt
```

this code needs to go in the event handler function of the `mainscreen`. Since you have not posted the complete code, I can't show it to you.

Hope this helps though.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you think it is advisable to use input() in a GUI? I think the GUI will freeze and the GUI will probably break.

Comment: Not at all. I do not advise taking input from terminal when using GUI. Since I didn't have a code to look at, I assumed that this was the case.

Comment: If I were in a console application I would use input() but in a GUI there should be widgets that are used for input, so if you know something about kivy you should use TextInput, don't you think it's reasonable?

Comment: I'm sorry for not pasting the whole code. It is available here: https://pastebin.com/00dx1xGp